# Invalid Encoding json (problem when displaying Cyrillic)

Tags: php, json

I am trying to deduce a file from the form, I have a problem when displaying Cyrillic

Php (7.1)

```php
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    file_put_contents('export.json', json_encode($_REQUEST) );
?>
```

Output
You_name field is written in characters.

```
{"Entry_ID":"71","You_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0437\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0431\u0435\u043a \u0410\u043c\u0438\u0440 \u041f\u043e\u043c\u0438\u0434\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0447","You_phone":"7 (902) 998 1019","You_date":"19\/06\/2019"}
```

Comment: It looks right to me.  When you read the file, you need to use json_decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 year old answer still stands: [Why does the PHP json_encode function convert UTF-8 strings to hexadecimal entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit)

```php
json_encode( $text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Example:

```sh
/tmp $ cat test.php
<?php
echo json_encode(['key'=>'ыфва']), PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(['key'=>'ыфва'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), PHP_EOL;
/tmp $ php test.php
{"key":"\u044b\u0444\u0432\u0430"}
{"key":"ыфва"}
/tmp $ php --version
PHP 7.3.6 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 23:38:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.6, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.6, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I am trying Php (7.1), 6 year old answeк for  PHP/5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You should use $_POST to get the form data like as below

```
  header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

  file_put_contents('export.json', json_encode($_POST) );
```

Comment: I tried $_POST, but still Cyrillic is not displayed... Also iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $str)

Comment: ... and file_put_contents('export.json', iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $str) , FILE_APPEND);

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963377/file-get-contents-on-file-with-cyrillic-characters-and-undefined-encoding)) :

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8")

$convert = file_put_contents('export.json', json_encode($_REQUEST));
$convert = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $convert);
```